# How to use a wildcard in egrep?

Tags: grep

Can I use a wildcard '?' in egrep?
I just want to print match strings starting with '02' or '03' from Data.

Tried below command, but it doesn't help.

```
egrep '03/??/16|02/??/16' test
```

## Data

```
01/19/16
02/19/16
02/13/16
03/04/16
03/05/16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you actually looked at the `egrep`'s man page? There is written that `?` specifies that the preceding item is optionally matched at most once (i.e. zero times or once). What you are probably looking for is the `.` pattern which matches exactly one character.

What you need is probably

```
egrep '03/../16|02/../16' test
```

or

```
egrep '(03|02)/../16' test
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.` instead of `?` to match a single char like this:

`egrep '03/../16|02/../16' test`

or  use proper number character classes

`egrep '(03|02)/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}' test`

Comment: Thanks. Learned about '.'.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
egrep '0[2,3]/[0-9]{2}/16' test
```

this will print match strings starting with '02' or '03